# Once BLE bonding is comptete, can I use encryption keys to encrypt a broadcast message?

Tags: encryption, bluetooth-lowenergy, broadcast, ads

At the flowcharting stage of my program.  I would like to save energy by sending a couple of attributes in my advertising broadcast message but am worried that a radio closer to my central could spoof my message and supply bogus data using my advertisers address. Can I pair then bond and then use encryption keys to encrypt my two attributes in the broadcast message? Please refer me to a more appropriate forum if this question does not belong here.

Answer (score 0):

The normal Bluetooth Core standard does not define any way of securing advertising data. The encryption keys exchanged at pairing can only be used for securing an established connection.

You have to invent your own layer or use for example Bluetooth Mesh.